# JQGrid Default button for adding

Tags: c#, .net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm new to JQgrid and can't figure out how to add a default button to the Add part of the grid.

So there is a grid with rows that have the columns: "Date, name and dose" for a medications grid. When they press the add medication button at the bottom it opens the add medication dialog with three textfields for them to add this information. All I want to do is make it so that when they press "Enter" on this dialog it adds the medication. So that the don't have to press the add button in the dialog.

I don't even know where to put this in the JQGrid code, which is very big so I don't know which code to post, if anyone tells me sort of where I need to post it I can post code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter [savekey:[true,13]](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) of Add/Edit forms will solve your problem.

For example,

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{/*navGrid options*/},
                  {savekey:[true,13]},  // edit options
                  {savekey:[true,13]}); // add options
```

Because you probably want to have the settings in all the grids which you use you can prefer to change the default option of jqGrid for Add/Edit dialog on one place:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm:true,
    jqModal:false,
    reloadAfterSubmit:false,
    savekey: [true,13],
    closeOnEscape:true,
    closeAfterAdd:true,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. As you can see I just figured this out but I wish I had seen yours earlier. Marking you as answer.

Comment: @Loogawa: You are welcome! i appended my answer with one more way which I personally prefer to use.

Comment: That is very helpful code. In this situation I will only ever have one grid in one place but It is helpful to know for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is an option that should go with the rest of your add dialog options.

```
bSubmit: "Add",
savekey: [true,13],
url: '<%=urlAddMedication%>',
```

The one in the middle is the solution, the other lines given for context.

savekey is the option for button to save, it needs an array of length 2. The first element is boolean depending on whether it should save or not. The second is the keycode of the button in question. (13 is the code for the enter key)